# Installing gtk2 gem on ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, compilation, debian, gtk2

Im currently running debian 10 operating system. I try to install gtk2 gem for ruby but I have the following error. I updated gcc and libtool but I got the same error. I have already installed ruby-dev, and updated all the gem but I'm stuck with this error

```
gem install gtk2
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing gtk2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.3/ext/gobject-introspection
/usr/bin/ruby2.7 -I /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20201218-8651-102gp3h.rb extconf.rb
checking for --enable-debug-build option... no
checking for -Wall option to compiler... yes
checking for -Waggregate-return option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wcast-align option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wextra option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wformat=2 option to compiler... yes
checking for -Winit-self option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wlarger-than-65500 option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-declarations option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-format-attribute option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-include-dirs option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-noreturn option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-prototypes option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wnested-externs option to compiler... no
checking for -Wold-style-definition option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wpacked option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wpointer-arith option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wundef option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wout-of-line-declaration option to compiler... no
checking for -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wwrite-strings option to compiler... yes
checking for Homebrew... no
checking for gobject-introspection-1.0... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.7
    --enable-debug-build
    --disable-debug-build
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-override-variables
    --without-override-variables

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/gobject-introspection-3.4.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/gobject-introspection-3.4.3/gem_make.out
```

I can run ruby on xubuntu 20.04 without problem.

Comment: Is the above output really the full error message?

Comment: No, i just edited my first post with all the output.

Answer (score -1):

I just tried, here is the output of my shell:

```
apt install ruby2.5-dev
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet ruby2.5-dev
E: Impossible de trouver de paquet correspondant à l'expression rationnelle « ruby2.5-dev »
```

In english: Impossible to find the ruby2.5-dev

Then

```
gem install gtk2 -v 3.0.7
```

Give me the following:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing gtk2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/glib2-3.0.7/ext/glib2
/usr/bin/ruby2.7 -I /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20201218-12598-grzx1f.rb extconf.rb
checking for --enable-debug-build option... no
checking for -Wall option to compiler... yes
checking for -Waggregate-return option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wcast-align option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wextra option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wformat=2 option to compiler... yes
checking for -Winit-self option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wlarger-than-65500 option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-declarations option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-format-attribute option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-include-dirs option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-noreturn option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wmissing-prototypes option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wnested-externs option to compiler... no
checking for -Wold-style-definition option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wpacked option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wpointer-arith option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wswitch-default option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wswitch-enum option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wundef option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wout-of-line-declaration option to compiler... no
checking for -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations option to compiler... yes
checking for -Wwrite-strings option to compiler... yes
checking for rb_define_alloc_func() in ruby.h... yes
checking for rb_block_proc() in ruby.h... yes
checking for new allocation framework... yes
checking for attribute assignment... no
checking for Windows... no
checking for gobject-2.0 version (>= 2.12.0)... yes
checking for gthread-2.0... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for io.h... no
checking for g_spawn_close_pid() in glib.h... yes
checking for g_thread_init() in glib.h... yes
checking for g_main_depth() in glib.h... yes
checking for g_listenv() in glib.h... yes
checking for rb_check_array_type() in ruby.h... yes
checking for rb_check_hash_type() in ruby.h... yes
checking for rb_exec_recursive() in ruby.h... yes
checking for rb_errinfo() in ruby.h... yes
checking for rb_sourcefile() in ruby.h... yes
checking for rb_sourceline() in ruby.h... yes
checking for ruby_set_current_source() in ruby.h... no
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby.h... yes
checking for ruby_native_thread_p() in ruby.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl() in ruby.h... yes
checking for rb_str_new_cstr() in ruby.h... yes
checking for rb_gc_register_mark_object() in ruby.h... yes
checking for rb_exc_new_str() in ruby.h... yes
checking for curr_thread in ruby.h,node.h... no
checking for rb_curr_thread in ruby.h,node.h... no
creating ruby-glib2.pc
creating glib-enum-types.c
creating glib-enum-types.h
creating Makefile

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/glib2-3.0.7/ext/glib2
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/glib2-3.0.7/ext/glib2
make "DESTDIR="
compiling glib-enum-types.c
In file included from glib-enum-types.c:4:
glib-enum-types.h:119: warning: "G_TYPE_UNICODE_TYPE" redefined
  119 | #define G_TYPE_UNICODE_TYPE (g_unicode_type_get_type())
      | 
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:25,
                 from glib-enum-types.h:7,
                 from glib-enum-types.c:4:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/glib-enumtypes.h:13: note: this is the location of the previous definition
   13 | #define G_TYPE_UNICODE_TYPE (g_unicode_type_get_type ())
      | 
In file included from glib-enum-types.c:4:
glib-enum-types.h:121: warning: "G_TYPE_UNICODE_BREAK_TYPE" redefined
  121 | #define G_TYPE_UNICODE_BREAK_TYPE (g_unicode_break_type_get_type())
      | 
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:25,
                 from glib-enum-types.h:7,
                 from glib-enum-types.c:4:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/glib-enumtypes.h:15: note: this is the location of the previous definition
   15 | #define G_TYPE_UNICODE_BREAK_TYPE (g_unicode_break_type_get_type ())
      | 
In file included from glib-enum-types.c:4:
glib-enum-types.h:123: warning: "G_TYPE_UNICODE_SCRIPT" redefined
  123 | #define G_TYPE_UNICODE_SCRIPT (g_unicode_script_get_type())
      | 
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:25,
                 from glib-enum-types.h:7,
                 from glib-enum-types.c:4:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/glib-enumtypes.h:17: note: this is the location of the previous definition
   17 | #define G_TYPE_UNICODE_SCRIPT (g_unicode_script_get_type ())
      | 
In file included from glib-enum-types.c:4:
glib-enum-types.h:125: warning: "G_TYPE_NORMALIZE_MODE" redefined
  125 | #define G_TYPE_NORMALIZE_MODE (g_normalize_mode_get_type())
      | 
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:25,
                 from glib-enum-types.h:7,
                 from glib-enum-types.c:4:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/glib-enumtypes.h:19: note: this is the location of the previous definition
   19 | #define G_TYPE_NORMALIZE_MODE (g_normalize_mode_get_type ())
      | 
glib-enum-types.c: In function ‘g_test_subprocess_flags_get_type’:
glib-enum-types.c:279:12: warning: initialization of ‘unsigned int’ from ‘const char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  279 |       { }, "}", "}" },
      |            ^~~
glib-enum-types.c:279:12: note: (near initialization for ‘values[4].value’)
glib-enum-types.c:279:12: error: initializer element is not computable at load time
glib-enum-types.c:279:12: note: (near initialization for ‘values[4].value’)
glib-enum-types.c:279:7: warning: missing initializer for field ‘value_nick’ of ‘GFlagsValue’ {aka ‘const struct _GFlagsValue’} [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
  279 |       { }, "}", "}" },
      |       ^
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:24,
                 from glib-enum-types.h:7,
                 from glib-enum-types.c:4:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/genums.h:213:16: note: ‘value_nick’ declared here
  213 |   const gchar *value_nick;
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~
glib-enum-types.c:275:41: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
  275 |     static const GFlagsValue values[] = {
      |                                         ^
......
  279 |       { }, "}", "}" },
      |            {        }
glib-enum-types.c:280:7: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
  280 |       { G_GNUC_BEGIN_IGNORE_DEPRECATIONS, "G_GNUC_BEGIN_IGNORE_DEPRECATIONS", "g-gnuc-begin-ignore-deprecations" },
      |       ^
glib-enum-types.c:280:115: error: expected expression before ‘,’ token
  280 |       { G_GNUC_BEGIN_IGNORE_DEPRECATIONS, "G_GNUC_BEGIN_IGNORE_DEPRECATIONS", "g-gnuc-begin-ignore-deprecations" },
      |                                                                                                                   ^
glib-enum-types.c:280:115: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
glib-enum-types.c:280:115: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
glib-enum-types.c:275:30: warning: unused variable ‘values’ [-Wunused-variable]
  275 |     static const GFlagsValue values[] = {
      |                              ^~~~~~
glib-enum-types.c:291:62: error: ‘values’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  291 |     etype = g_flags_register_static ("GTestSubprocessFlags", values);
      |                                                              ^~~~~~
glib-enum-types.c:291:62: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
glib-enum-types.c: At top level:
glib-enum-types.c:293:3: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘return’
  293 |   return etype;
      |   ^~~~~~
glib-enum-types.c:294:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘}’ token
  294 | }
      | ^
glib-enum-types.c: In function ‘g_spawn_error_get_type’:
glib-enum-types.c:795:7: warning: ‘G_SPAWN_ERROR_2BIG’ is deprecated: Use 'G_SPAWN_ERROR_TOO_BIG' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  795 |       { G_SPAWN_ERROR_2BIG, "G_SPAWN_ERROR_2BIG", "2big" },
      |       ^
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:81,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gbinding.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h:22,
                 from glib-enum-types.h:7,
                 from glib-enum-types.c:4:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gspawn.h:76:3: note: declared here
   76 |   G_SPAWN_ERROR_2BIG GLIB_DEPRECATED_ENUMERATOR_IN_2_32_FOR(G_SPAWN_ERROR_TOO_BIG) = G_SPAWN_ERROR_TOO_BIG,
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
glib-enum-types.c: In function ‘g_test_subprocess_flags_get_type’:
glib-enum-types.c:292:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  292 |   }
      |   ^
At top level:
glib-enum-types.c:275:30: warning: ‘values’ defined but not used [-Wunused-const-variable=]
  275 |     static const GFlagsValue values[] = {
      |                              ^~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:245 : glib-enum-types.o] Erreur 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/glib2-3.0.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/glib2-3.0.7/gem_make.out
```